# multiselect table elements

Tags: jquery

I have a calender that shows date in table format. 
I have click event on each of the `<td>` elements for some additional function processing. Can  multi-select with **Ctrl** be enabled on the table elements and do the function call for all the dates selected in one go? Thanks.

Below is the code :

```
$("#table_calender td").live('click', function(e){

    if($(this).hasClass('booked')){
     alert('already booked');
    }
    else{
          if(e.ctrlKey) {
            alert('ctrl clicked');
          }
          else {
            alert('not booked');
          }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure.
You can do it. But you may have to write some code.

add a hidden input.
while clicking the td. update the hidden with the dates selected. hilite the dates upon selection.

Comment: Thanks , i have updated my question with the code. I can now update the hidden input field with the ctrl key checking. But how do i detect when ctrl key is released.